# How can I append a word in between an array of strings?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I want to append the word `AND` between each string in an array, but I don't want it at the end of my string.  Here is what I'm trying:

Assuming I want to pass `First, Second, Third`

```
public void addString(String... myString) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   for(int i = 0; i < myString.length -1;) {
      sb.append("(" + myString[i] + " AND " + myString[i+1] + ")");
      i++;
   }

   System.out.println(sb);
}
```

My output is `(First AND Second)(Second AND Third)`

But I want `(First AND Second AND Third)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The output tells you what you're doing wrong. You're writing parentheses at each iteration, and each value is appended twice. You should be able to figure that out by yourself.

Comment: @Downvoter, what did I do?  Wow..

Comment: I'm not understanding how my question is getting down votes?

Comment: Downvotes are based on people's oppinion. It's hard to come up with something meaningful, but some have less tolerance to certain kind of questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Append the `"("` before your `for` loop so it prints only once.  Similarly, append the `")"` after your `for` loop so it prints only once.  Finally, you can loop through your entire `myString` array, appending only that element, instead of two elements at a time, and only appending `" AND "` if needed.

Answer (score 4):

Tweak your answer like this:

```
public void addString(String... myString) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");

   for(int i = 0; i < myString.length -1; i++) {
      sb.append(myString[i] + " AND ");
   }
   if(myString.length == 0)
       sb.append(")");
   else
       sb.append(myString[myString.length - 1]);
   System.out.println(sb);
}
```

The only changes are:

- Create the `StringBuilder` containing the starting `(`
- Add all the elements except the last one, and append `"AND"` after it
- Add the final element and the closing `)`

The repetitive part of your algorithm is the one that places the inner elements. This also covers the case where `myString` has length `1`. In case of having no elements, the last addition is skipped and the closing ")" is added.

Answer (score 3):

You should seperate the parts that you want just once from you for loop like this. So you want ( and ) once and there is only one word for wich you dont need AND in front of it.

```
public void addString(String[] myString) 
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.append("("+myString[0]);
   for(int i = 1; i < myString.length;i++) 
   {
      sb.append(" AND " + myString[i]);
   }
   sb.append(")")

   System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To do what you want I'd probably use the `join` method in StringUtils.

[StringUtils.join Docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%29)

From the docs:

```
public static String join(Object[] array,
          String separator)

Joins the elements of the provided array into a single String containing the provided list of elements.

No delimiter is added before or after the list. A null separator is the same as an empty String (""). Null objects or empty strings within the array are represented by empty strings.

 StringUtils.join(null, *)                = null
 StringUtils.join([], *)                  = ""
 StringUtils.join([null], *)              = ""
 StringUtils.join(["a", "b", "c"], "--")  = "a--b--c"
 StringUtils.join(["a", "b", "c"], null)  = "abc"
 StringUtils.join(["a", "b", "c"], "")    = "abc"
 StringUtils.join([null, "", "a"], ',')   = ",,a"


Parameters:
    array - the array of values to join together, may be null
    separator - the separator character to use, null treated as ""
Returns:
    the joined String, null if null array input
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following -

```
Arrays.asList(myString).toString().replaceAll(",", " AND").replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")")
```

- `Arrays.asList(myString)` converts the `array` to a `List`.
- `toString()` converts it to a string which is like `[ele1, ele2, ele
  3]`.
- Then using the `replaceAll` and `replace` method gives the
  appropriate output.

The second option is to use the [`join`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) method provided by [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).

Answer (score 1):

The approach used most often when you want separators between elements is to add the separator first, then the string. Only skipping the separator before the first element.

```
public void addString(String... myString) {
    String separator = " AND ";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append('(');

    boolean needSeparator = false;
    for(String string : myString) {
        if (needSeparator) {
            sb.append(separator);
        } else {
            needSeparator = true;
        }
        sb.append(string);
    }

    sb.append(')');

    System.out.println(sb);
 }
```

If you call `addString("First", "Second", "Third")` you'd get

```
(First AND Second AND Third)
```

This works perfectly fine with just 1 input `addString("First")`

```
(First)
```

Or even empty input `addString()` which would crash most other solutions I've seen here

```
()
```

It is possible to move printing the first element out of the loop so the loop does not have to check if it needs to omit the separator (minimal performance gain) but that results IMO in less readable code. E.g.:

```
if (myString.length > 0) {
    // append first element without separator
    sb.append(myString[0]);

    // implicitly checks that length > 1
    for (int i = 1; i < myString.length; i++) {
        // append separator unconditionally
        sb.append(separator);
        sb.append(myString[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the `parenthesis` before and after the `For Loop`.

Append only one `element` in the `String` at a time.

Remove the final "AND " at the end of the `String` after the `For Loop`.

```
public void addString(String... myString) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("(");

    for(int i = 0; i < myString.length;) {
        sb.append(myString[i] + " AND ");
        i++;
    }

    sb = sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 5);

    sb.append(")");

    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't want repeated `()`.

Comment: This is wrong. because after the last word in the list there will be another AND where it is not supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Apache CommonsLang package http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

then use its StringUtils join() method as described here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.join(myString, ' AND '));
```

Answer (score -1):

Corrected code:

```
 public void addString(String... myString) {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

       for(int i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
          if(i = 0){
             sb.append("(" + myString[i])
          }else if (i = myString.length-1){
             sb.append(myString[i] + ")");
          }else{
             sb.append(myString[i])
          }
          sb.append("(" + myString[i] + " AND " + myString[i+1] + ")");
       }

       System.out.println(sb);
    }
```

**EDIT**: Here is a better version based off of one of the answers above:

```
public void addString(String[] myString) 
    {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append("(");
       for(int i = 0; i < myString.length; i++){
          sb.append(myString[i] + " AND ");
       }
       sb.append(")")

       System.out.println(sb);
    }
```

Comment: The if else structure just wastes time. the parts that you need onces should be put before and after the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public void addString(string[] myString) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   sb.Append("(");
   for(int i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
      sb.Append(myString[i] + " AND ");
   }

   string result = sb.ToString().Substring(0, sb.ToString().LastIndexOf("AND"));
   result += ")";

   System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Fix your lowercase/uppercase.